# Typescript array of arrays of arrays: protect from undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am parsing a complex object in Typescript, so have something like:

```
const a = reply['price']['value']['total']['value'];
```

and I like to ensure that all elements are defined in the chain, otherwise, it should set `a=0` and do not trigger an exception if some of the chained keys are in fact undefined.

What would be the appropriate syntax for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using modern JS you can use [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
const a = reply?.['price']?.['value']?.['total']?.['value'] ?? 0;
```

Try to avoid using `||` instead of `??`, because that will give you `0`, if the final value is any falsy value, like `0` or `false`.

If you don't want to use nullish coalescing, you can do this, which achieves the same.

```
const a = reply?.['price']?.['value']?.['total']?.['value'] ? reply['price']['value']['total']['value'] : 0;
```

Comment: I think using || in this case is actually better. Considering the name is value, probably 0 is what you want and not false.

Comment: I guess it could be reasoned that if the value is `false`, and we are checking for the value, `false` is what they actually want

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use @nullptr 's answer, I suggest creating a function for that purpose :

```js
function getObjectNestedValue2(obj, keys, defaultValue) {
    let currObjOrValue = obj;
    keys.forEach(key => {
        if (!currObjOrValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            currObjOrValue = defaultValue;
            return;
        }
        currObjOrValue = currObjOrValue[key];
    });
    return currObjOrValue;
}
```

You then call it like so :

```js
const a = getObjectNestedValue(reply, ['price', 'value', 'total', 'value'], 0);
```

Cheers

Comment: the question is tagged as typescript, so you'll have to provide the type for the function as well. the function you provided will throw errors if implicitAny is set to false